# How to create an admin panel in Asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Please help me in making a admin panel in MVC4.
   can anyone supply me with the stepwise coding if i want to create it from scratch..
   Thanks in Advance..

This is my basic model what next???

```
public class userlogon
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Admin Login")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "what next???" [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) is next !!

Comment: `what next???` - you could start reading ASP.NET MVC tutorials. Here's a good place: http://asp.net/mvc You could come back here once you have a specific programming related question, showing the progress you have made so far and explaining the particular difficulties you have encountered with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to study from this web site.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

For me it was very helpful. It shows you step by step what to do. It's the best way to learn MVC.